Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection ...Project.issues: no Session
Project Name: Project-Manager
I am trying to implement a service class which would fetch all the projects or single projects from the DB by id but in both the cases I am getting this lazy initialization error
I tried swtitching fetch mode to eager but the problem still persists
Here is my project model
...

public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String category;
    private LocalDate startDate;
    private LocalDate endDate;
    private Boolean status;


    @ElementCollection
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "project", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Chat chat;

    @ManyToOne
    private User owner;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Issues> issues = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany
    private List<User> team = new ArrayList<>();

   

}


My ProjectService implementation:
...
    @Override
    public List<Project> getAllProjects(User user) throws Exception {
        return repo.findByTeamContainingOrOwner(user,user);
    }


    @Override
    public List<Project> getProjectByTeam(User user, String category, String tag) throws Exception {
        List<Project> projects = repo.findByTeamContainingOrOwner(user,user);

        if(category!=null){
            projects = projects.stream().filter(project -> project.getCategory().equals(category)).toList();
        }

        if(tag!=null){
            projects = projects.stream().filter(project -> project.getTags().contains(tag)).toList();
        }

        return projects;
    }


    @Override
    public Project getProjectById(Long Id) throws Exception {
        Optional<Project> project = repo.findById(Id);

        if(project.isEmpty()){
            throw new Exception("Project not found");
        }
        return project.get();
    }
...


}


and finally my Project Controller
...

    //get all projects
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Project>> getProjects(
            @RequestParam(required = false)String category,
            @RequestParam(required = false)String tag,
            @RequestHeader("Authorization")String jwt
    ) throws Exception {
        User user = userService.findUserProfileByJwt(jwt);
        List<Project> projects = projectService.getAllProjects(user);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(projects, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    //get project by id
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Project> getProjectById(
            @PathVariable("id")Long ProjectId,
            @RequestHeader("Authorization")String jwt
    ) throws Exception {
        User user = userService.findUserProfileByJwt(jwt);
        Project project = projectService.getProjectById(ProjectId);


        return new ResponseEntity<>(project, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

...


}


I tried switching fetch type to eager as well as removing the entire tags section from my code but the problem then arise for the "issues" entity too.

This question is similar to: LazyInitializationException Spring Boot. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

whats the reason for not including the full error in your question?
